# Build a site wordpress or ftp

Tags: html, wordpress, ftp

I want to build a website but I don't have a domain (I will get one soon) and a host so I'm confussed how can a website be built because I don't want it to make it wrong from the beginning. I can make it static (notepad++) and then publish it into my domain using ftp or create it using wordpress locally (make a server on my computer) and then publish on my domain. So if I want to update my site made in notepad++ can I use wordpress? And if I use wordpress do I need to use ftp anymore? My website will be like a blog with different articles so I will update it regularly. I know enough HTML and CSS for building my site and never published a website before so i don't know the correct steps.
I accept any advice thanks.

Comment: Create a local server on your computer for the time of development and publish your Wordpress theme/plugins after your domain has been setup for you. Read the documentation of Worpdress to find out more about how you install it and what your server environment needs, go to wordpress.org.

Comment: This isn't really on-topic for a few reasons. It's asking what kind of software to use, which makes it an off-topic request for recommendations. It's asking primarily about how to create and administer websites, not about programming, which means it's also off-topic for that reason. And it's extremely broad. Please read about [ask] questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has 2 possible answers

**Short Answer:**
You can use HTML and CSS that you write every time for a new article, or if you use wordpress you'll have an article management dashboard.

**Long Answer:**
FTP and Wordpress are 2 completely different things. Wordpress is a CMS (Content Managing System) and what that means in plain english is that Wordpress is a platform for building websites.
 
Blogs need databases and all kinds of backend functionalities which can't be Done with plain HTML and CSS. (You need a backend language like PHP, the language wordpress is built in)
HTML and CSS are still the building blocks of the frontend(visual) part of the website, only the backend is the actual management part. Wordpress handles all that backend logic with databases and so on, so that you won't have to. 
It's probably the easiest to install blogging platform.

If you choose the "manual" version, writing all the HTML and CSS by hand will take you quite a while every time you make a new page or article. Wordpress has its templates that handle that part for you as well, leaving you to only take care of the content, or text of the website. 
Also, wordpress has 1000s of themes and plugin that can help make your site more complex without very much technical knowledge on that part, and benefiting from a huge worldwide community, wordpress also has a huge knowledge base(tutorials, guides etc).

FTP is the protocol used to transfer files, and if your host does not have a one-click install for wordpress you will have to download wordpress and push it to the server via FTP.

I hope you found my answer useful, If you want to learn a lot I suggest the manual way, maybe even learn some PHP. If you just want a clean blogging experience, wordpress is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a blog.you should know,it have 2 type of blog:dynamic one and static one.a static one just like hexo and the dynamic one is just like wordpress.if you want to use wordpress. you need a website create with php server create by apache or nginx, a database for wordpress to storage. create and edit posts in website admin page.
you need know how to install web service , database, wordpress .dont worry.its simple.:)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1-  make your **static website** using just html and righting your text and tags updating to your server.

or:

2- make your website **dynamic**: using WordPress, so like that you don't need change your text and tags offline and send it by ftp, you just need to use the admin panel and make that changes.

p.s: you will need ftp for send your template and codes, text, images can be done just using WordPress admin panel.

you ca watch this video and learn more.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiaT4bR3xGA

let me know if I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't have to be confused just yet, start building :)

I will give you a little intro that might make it easy for you to start.

- HTML and CSS are the building blocks of any website. So since you already know your life developing website is going to be a lot easier than other folks.
- WordPress is built with the following languages - HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP. And a few more such as SQL.
- Building WordPress website locally needs some preparation. You have to make your computer into an Apache local server that runs PHP and can work SQL. HTML and CSS will work in any browser but to make PHP and SQL run (Which is required for WordPress) you have to make your computer into a local server. How do you do that? Just install XAMPP - [LINK](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)
- Building a WordPress website is nothing like building with HTML and CSS. Its way more easier because everything is prebuilt. Even connection with the SQL database is prebuilt. So your life is way easier. You do not have to connect your PHP to SQL and all that stuff which developers commonly do.
- For WordPress as a beginner you have to only learn two important features. They are Themes and Plugins. If you want to know what they are here you do - [WORDPRESS PLUGIN](https://ithemes.com/tutorials/what-are-wordpress-plugins/), [WORDPRESS THEME](https://ithemes.com/tutorials/what-is-a-wordpress-theme/). Read those articles, you will get a good idea.
- Now, if you want to be a hardcore web developer using WordPress you will have to again start using CSS, PHP and all the basic languages. Because remember, WordPress is built in these languages! So if you are planning to do that you can use NotePad++. A better option is Coda or Sublime Text. But I bet you wont need that atleast for a few months.

Now I gave you enough leads to read about. 
Time to hustle :)